# Troubleshooting with two python distributions

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, uninstallation

I downloaded Anaconda3 to use Jupyter Notebook and some other applications. However, when trying to import Seaborn I received the following error message
[image]

I checked to see if seaborn was properly installed by using the python -m pip install, and the output was a list of "Requirements already satisfied..." I believe the issue is that I have two distributions of pythons running on my pc, as can be seen here:
[image]
Since the error in Jupyter Notebook refers to AppData/Local, I imagine the issue is that Seaborn isn't installed in the AppData/Local python.exe because it's trying to import from there. I don't really know what the best solution is here. I could delete one of the python programs. Or I could tell Jupyter to import using anaconda3 python. But I'm not sure how to do either of those things.

I tried deleting the python.exe located in AppData/Local but the action was interrupted: "An unexpected error is keeping you from deleting the file..."

I appreciate any tips/advice. Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to delete anything. you can just use different virtual environments. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: @shivankgtm thank you, I've started to look into creating virtual environments. I have a question. There's an .ipynb file on my dektop that already has a code in it for importing packages/processing data, and it runs on the python3 kernel. If I create a new environment with the python3 kernel and transfer that ipynb file into the new environment, wouldn't I receive the same error when trying to import packages like Seaborn?

Comment: you can ```pip install seaborn``` in virtual env if it comes. virtual env is only work is to keep the different working environments separate.